(DenyAll or permitAll) with (hasAnyRole or hasAnyAuthority), and() is deprecated
I'm learning about Spring Security I'm using these dependencies.
implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security', version: '3.2.4'

and() is deprecated!
I'm trying configure the access to my endpoints by coincidence.
private static Customizer<AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.AuthorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry>
        getAuthorizationManagerRequestByCoincidence() {
    return authorizeHttpRequestsCustomizer -> {

// I would like to pass All with this pattern /api/users

        authorizeHttpRequestsCustomizer
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/users")
                .permitAll();

// Except this ROLES

        authorizeHttpRequestsCustomizer
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/users")
                .hasAnyRole("USER2", "USER")
                .requestMatchers("*")
                .denyAll();

// All others must be authenticated

        authorizeHttpRequestsCustomizer
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/authenticate")
                .permitAll();

        authorizeHttpRequestsCustomizer
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    };
}

As you can see, some snippet code is commented. They are commented because I get:
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-04-08T09:59:54.568-05:00 ERROR 14328 --- [ms-people] [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/bz/app/mspeople/security/configurations/HttpSecurityConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'securityFilterChain' threw exception with message: Can't configure mvcMatchers after anyRequest
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:648) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]

I understood I can't use something like denyAll() or permitAll() after anyRequest() but I was reading this https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/authorize-http-requests.html#match-by-httpmethod By I can't find my mistake.
About this question Can't configure antMatchers after anyRequest (Multiple antMatcher)
The error are same, but My question is like follow:
How I could use for hasAnyRole(...) or hasAnyAuthority(...) with denyAll()?

Does this answer your question? Can't configure antMatchers after anyRequest (Multiple antMatcher)

Because I understood I can't use something like denyAll() or permitAll() after anyRequest(), that is my question: How I could use for hasAnyRole(...) or hasAnyAuthority(...) with denyAll()?
